# How to Add Watermarks to Images in TPPDF Document?

Tags: tppdf

What's the best way to add watermarks to images in a TPPDF document?

Is this approach ([#19](https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF/issues/19)) still the best way? If so, would you mind please elaborating on how you'd do this?

I've found if I add watermarks to an image before adding to the document, the image resizing distorts the watermarks.

Thanks for taking a look.

**Update**
In case anyone else is interested in this enhancement, I created this [PR](https://github.com/techprimate/TPPDF/pull/232/files) with a possible solution; it adds a closure to PDFImage that takes in the CGImage's context and frame, so you can add your watermark after the image is resized and drawn.